# MFC: Does CWnd::SendMessage() only send messages to its class, or can other classes catch it?

Tags: c++, mfc, sendmessage

Let's say I have a list component class called ListCtrl that derives from CWnd.

And let's say I also have a dialog class called DialogA that derives from CDialog.

DialogA uses ListCtrl to map it to a list component. For example,

```
void DialogA::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX) 
{ 
    CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_LIST_CONTROL, listCtrl);
}
```

Where

```
ListCtrl listCtrl;
```

So if ListCtrl were to call the SendMessage(), can DialogA handle it?

If not, how can I have DialogA handle something that ListCtrl does.

Ultimately, I want DialogA to use a "copy" function of it's own when the ListCtrl right-click menu option for "Copy" is clicked, and prevent the copy function of ListCtrl from executing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CWnd::SendMessage` will send a message to the window wrapped by that `CWnd` derived class. So if you use `SendMessage` from your `ListCtrl` (which is a child window of your dialog), the dialog *won't* see it.

You either need to have the raw `HWND` of the dialog window and use the global `SendMessage` like:

```
::SendMessage(hWnd, WM_WHATEVER, 0, 0); // note the "::" scoping operator
```

Or you can possibly use the parent window of your list control (assuming that the dialog is its parent):

```
GetParent()->SendMessage(WM_WHATEVER, 0, 0);
```

In this last case, it would be more robust to ensure that `GetParent()` does not return `NULL` so perhaps:

```
CWnd *pParent = GetParent();
if (pParent != NULL)
    pParent->SendMessage(WM_WHATEVER, 0, 0);
else
    // error handling
```

Answer (score 1):

Any window (and a control is child window) can send a message to any window in the same process.

The question is if that's a good idea for your use case.

Perhaps, if you're going to derive a class for the list control anyway, just pass it a pointer to an object it can call member functions on as appropriate for whatever it's doing.

Comment: Weird because it's not working for me. I used SendMessage( COPY_MSG ) in ListCtrl, but my DialogA::PreTranslateMessage() isn't catching it. Where COPY_MSG = (WM_APP+1).

Comment: So you probably did it wrong. Show some code if you need help with it.